# SOAP with HTTP basic auth: put username+password in soapAction urls?

Tags: php, soap, basic-authentication

We are protecting a SOAP web service with HTTP basic authentication, so that the WSDL URL is e.g. https://user:pass@example.org/api?wsdl .

Should we add username and password in the soapAction attributes of the WSDL?

This would make it trivially easy to use the web service, since you only have to pass the WSDL url to your soap client and are set.
If we do not put it in the soapAction URLs, one has to explicitely configure the soap client with the username and password (apart from the wsdl url).

On the other hand, putting user+pass in the wsdl means that the sensitive authentication data may get cached, as PHP does it for WSDL files.

What should we do?